# Negation and implication verification 10

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am in math and statistics and have taken everything from linear algebra to multi variable calculus and just started a mathematical reasoning which is really making my head spin (in a good way) but I am second guessing myself quite a bit.

Question:

Let $U$ be the universe under sconsideration, and let $P(x)$ and Q(x) be predicates with free variable $x$. Find the negation of each statement.

**a.** $$(\forall x\in U)(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$$

answer: $$(\exists x\in U)(P(x) \bigwedge \sim  Q(x))$$

**b.** $$(\forall x\in U)(Q(x) \bigvee P(x))$$

answer: $$(\exists x\in U)(\sim Q(x) \bigwedge \sim P(x))$$

**c.** $$(\exists x\in U)(Q(x) \bigwedge P(x))$$

answer: $$(\forall x\in U)(\sim Q(x) \bigvee \sim P(x))$$

**d.** $$(\exists x\in U)(Q(x)  \bigwedge P(x))$$ (for d. use an implication in your answer)

answer: $$(\forall x\in U)(\sim Q(x) \bigvee \sim P(x))$$

I am pretty sure i got all of them right except for d. as I am not sure what it means to use an implication in my answer.

Comment: Some vagueness requiring you to convert "p or q" statements into "r implies s" statements which can be done two different ways and "p and q" statements into "not (r implies s)" statements which again, can be done in two different ways.  Yes, your work is correct.